# What are the possible tags and shortcuts used in Questions, answers and comments?

Tags: support

What are the possible tags and shortcuts used in Questions, answers and comments?

I know some thing like

{} or `` or Ctrl + K for code
** ** or Control B for bold

Is there documented anywhere?

<kbd>what is this</kbd> -- Where does this comes from then??

Comment: Um - hover over them? The keyboard shortcuts are in the tooltips.

Comment: I did, but some one pasted a <kdb>box</kbd> I couldn't find it anywhere??!! when i mean tag, it is this one and not the the topic tag

Comment: There is no keyboard shortcut for that. You would need to type out the whole thing.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Cool links.. THanks.. Post it as a answer.. I accept it

Comment: @realspirituals I don't think that asking for link-only answer is the best thing to do ;)

Comment: I do know that its not the best, but i could not find them in stack overflow and hence came here (with an expectation of getting the links on meta :) ) and got it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts show up as tooltips of the buttons they are on.

> [image: tooltip!]

Other features need to be typed in fully and you can learn all about them from the advanced [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

You can get editing help by clicking the `?` button at right end of the toolbar, which exposes a bar that will give help on different features, as well as a link to the advanced editing help:

> [image: question mark button]